# I have Error in copy specific elements in array of char in c#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a code .. but I have faced a problem .. I have tried to solve but I could not

The code which I tried to make it copy specific elements to another array of char
, btw I'm new in C#.

this is my code :

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        char[] A = s.ToCharArray();
        char[] B = new char[0];

        int i = 0;
        int start, end;
        int x = A.Length;
        string Bb ;

        while (x >0)
        {
            start = i + 1;
            end = start + 1;
            i = end + 2;
            Array.Copy(A, start, B, end, 2);

            x--;

        }

        Bb = new string(B);
        textBox6.Text = Bb;

    }
```

If you have any questions please don't be hesitate.

Comment: Give an example input, what your code produced from it, and what you wanted it to produce.

Comment: EX input:**1*234*5678

      output : *13467  

it will take 2 and skip 2

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer: You have to assign the size of character array `B` prior to using `Array.Copy`. You can't just expect it to resize dynamically to fit the contents you're trying to copy into it. If you need to do that, consider using `List` instead of `Array`.

Comment: `private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0; 
    textBox6.Text = String.Concat(s.Where(_ => (count++ / 2) % 2 == 0));
}`

Comment: @L.B: Are you trying to teach a beginner how to CodeGolf? ;)

Comment: @L.B when i use ur code the output is : **2356  >> for the input **1*234*5678 >> btw it should start from index 1 . and will take 2 and skip 2 >> and the output should be :  *13467.

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer Too easy to fix it but, I won't answer a question that posts the real specs after an hour.

Comment: @L.B I'm sorry :(((((((( 
please help me :(

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer: You can start at a direct index (like 1) by using `Skip`, as follows: `private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { int count = 0; textBox6.Text = String.Concat(s.Skip(1).Where(_ => (count++ / 2) % 2 == 0)); }` but I highly recommend using a `for` loop (such as my answer) or similar because they are more expressive and easy to read. This LINQ query is not as easily understood and it's debatable whether LINQ should even be used for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are simply better ways to write this kind of operation. For example, we can use a `StringBuilder` with a `while` loop to accomplish this, or use more advanced methods (such as LINQ). For example:

```
static private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length - 1; i += 4)
        stringBuilder.Append(s.Substring(i, 2));
    textBox6.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

This is a reasonably easy way to accomplish this. The variable naming is mostly straightforward, and it is easy to read.

We begin by instantiating a new `StringBuilder` to a variable called `stringBuilder`. This will store our entire output string.

Assign a start position by using `int i = 1`. This means we skipped one character at the beginning of the input string (because the positions are zero-based). You can easily change this to begin at other positions by adjusting this number.

Now use a `for` loop to iterate through all starting positions that we're interested in, as long as the starting position is less than the string length and the amount of characters we wish to include (`s.Length - 1`). During each iteration, we read a `Substring` of `s` starting at `i` and containing `2` characters. We append this to our `stringBuilder`.

After the substring has been read, we increment `i` by `4` to move to the next starting position.

Finally after all iterations have been completed, let the `stringBuilder` generate a new string for us using `ToString()`, and assign it to `textBox6.Text`.

If you want to include the elements at the end that don't make up a "full" `Substring` (ie. there is a single character at the end) you can use a conditional assignment to handle this quite easily.

As well, if you want to extend this to other `take X and skip X` places in your code, you can wrap the loop into method just for this.

```
static private string CustomTakeSkip(string inputText, int numTakeSkip)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = numTakeSkip - 1; i < inputText.Length; i += numTakeSkip * 2)
    {
        int nextStringLength = i + numTakeSkip > inputText.Length ? inputText.Length - i : numTakeSkip;
        stringBuilder.Append(inputText.Substring(i, nextStringLength));
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Note that this includes handling for the end cases you described by use of the conditional assignment (`condition ? valueWhenTrue : valueWhenFalse;` in `nextStringLength`.

You can call it like this:

```
textBox6.Text = CustomTakeSkip(s, 2);
textBox7.Text = CustomTakeSkip(s, 4);
```

Comment: Your code will throw exception for `string s = "0123456";`, How about testing it before writing a lof of unnecessary text.

Comment: @L.B: Thanks, edited. He stated that he was a beginner, so I wouldn't consider the text unnecessary.

Comment: @grovesNL Can I convert stringBuilder to int or array of int ?

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer: In the example you provided there are asterisks in the output. Obviously you can't convert an asterisk to an `int` unless you explicitly specify how you want this to behave. A string builder simply allows strings to be built in pieces (by concatenating new strings). However if you give us an example we can certainly look into it. You should submit this as a new question, with all of the specifications, and we'll be happy to answer it.

Comment: @grovesNL I'm trying to start from 4 and take 4 and skip 4>>i have some edit to ur code to be like this for take 4 and skip 4: 
            StringBuilder sb4 = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 3; i < s.Length - 3; i +=8)
            {
                sb4.Append(s.Substring(i, 4));
            }
            textBox7.Text = sb4.ToString();
>>first:is this true ? 
>>second:In the input is:**0*101*010101 the output should be :*101101 **BUT** the output from program is:*101 
**AND** for take 2 skip 2 with the same input the output should be:*001101  **BUT** the output is :*00110.& Thnx

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer: I edited my answer to include the cases where the end of the string does not qualify a complete `take(X)`. Note that adding detail through comments like this is generally not the way to request much more feedback on your question. For future questions please create a new question on StackOverflow and try to ask specific questions with all specifications provided. Try to post your questions in a way that would be useful to others and not your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better using a stringbuilder and a for loop to iterate through the chars like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i < s.Length - 1; i += 4)
{
    sb.Append(s.Substring(i, 2));
}
```

Didn't tried this (wrote it on tablet), but the meaning should be clear.

Comment: @L.B which skip part?

Comment: @roli09 No, If the input : **1*234*5678  >> the output should be *13467

Comment: the code will start from index 1 . and will take 2 and skip 2

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer `the code will start from index 1 . and will take 2 and skip 2` Only now you are saying this? How bad question?

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer I refreshed my code, should be ok now.

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer: All of that is explained clearly in my answer that is functionally equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to give size to array B while initializing.

//e.g Can be initialized to the size of A

char[] B = new char[A.Length];

Also, you are reducing x by 1 and incrementing i more than 2 times so you are bound to go out of index while copying from Array A to B.
You can try to update your while statement to,

while (x >0 && start < x && end < x)

Comment: when I do this update to the code I face Error in **While** statement  "(local variable) int end  used unassigned variable 'end'" why ?

Comment: you need to initialize start and end to 0.